# Como colocar o ISNULL no Subselect com case?

Tags: sql, sql-server, query

Como faço para em vez retornar `Null` retornar como `Não`. Estou com dúvidas quanto ao uso do `ISNULL` dentro do `Subselect` junto com o case.

Resultado:

```
Projeto teste     Null

Projeto OK        Sim.
```

Em vez de `Null` quero que me retorne `NÃO`, como faço?

```
SELECT DISTINCT concat(CC.Descricao,'-',U1.UsuNome),
                C.CompDesc QtdeCNPJs,

  (SELECT top 1 Faturado = CASE T1.TarEstagioID
                               WHEN 112 THEN 'SIM'
                               ELSE 'NÃO'
                           END
   FROM Projetos P
   INNER JOIN Tarefa T1 ON P.ProjID = T1.ProjID
   WHERE T1.TarStatus = 9
     AND T1.TarTitulo = 'Treinamento Realizado - Emitir Boleto Setup'
     AND P.ProjID = PP.ProjID
     AND T1.TarTipID = 674) Faturado
FROM PROJETOS PP
INNER JOIN Tarefa T ON PP.ProjID = T.ProjID
INNER JOIN Usuario U ON T.UsuIDResponsavel = U.UsuID
INNER JOIN Usuario U1 ON T.UsuIDCliente = U1.UsuID
LEFT JOIN Complemento C ON C.UsuID = T.UsuIDCliente
AND C.CompID = 1
LEFT JOIN CurvaABC CC ON (CC.CurvaID = U1.CurvaID)
WHERE CC.CurvaID = 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Renan,

Utilizei a função ISNULL do sqlServer.

Exemplo:

```
SELECT ISNULL(STATUS, 0) AS STATUS FROM T_TESTE
```

Nesta situação, caso o campo status venha nullo o mesmo será substituido por 0.

Se não conseguir, da uma olhada nesse post:

http://t-sql.com.br/como-utilizar-a-funcao-isnull-funcoes-sql-server-parte-5/

Comment: Isso ai eu sei como utilizar, pois é de um select simples, mas to tendo dificuldades na consulta citada, pois é um subselect.

Comment: Acho engraçado avaliarem minha resposta como negativa sendo que respondi a pergunta que havia sido feita. Após minha resposta foi editada a pergunta para  o que realmente ele precisava!

Answer (score -1):

O cálculo de "Faturado" pode ser reescrito para

```
-- código #1 v2
SELECT concat(CC.Descricao,'-', U1.UsuNome),
       C.CompDesc as QtdeCNPJs,    
       case when exists (SELECT * 
                           from Tarefa as T1
                           where T1.ProjID = PP.ProjID
                                 and T1.TarStatus = 9
                                 and T1.TarTitulo = 'Treinamento Realizado - Emitir Boleto Setup'
                                 and T1.TarTipID = 674
                                 and T1.TarEstagioID = 112)
            then 'SIM' 
            else 'NÃO' end as Faturado
  from PROJETOS as PP
...
```

É uma [subconsulta correlacionada](https://technet.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms187638.aspx).

Nessa subconsulta não é necessário utilizar a tabela Projetos; basta estabelecer o correlacionamento direto com a tabela Projetos da consulta externa.

Comment: ôpa grande José Diz, testei aqui, porém, ainda veio null na coluna Faturado. 

Null
Null
Sim
Null

Comment: @RenanBessa: O retorno da função EXISTS é booleano; ou true ou false. Desta forma, ou exibe o SIM ou o NÃO. Acrescentei no código #1 as demais colunas, para comparar com o que está utilizando. // O resultado que informou, "Null Null Sim Null", indica que a coluna Faturado, que é a terceira coluna, veio "Sim"?